# programmatically remove email signature in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Can I remove the signature "Sent from my iPad" for the mails sent from my app?
I have searched [the developer reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) but could not find any specific method for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to alter the settings of another application from within your iOS application.  If you are, however, building an email client, you may be able to regex it and remove it.