# Access the email signature boxes on iOS Mail app in mail, Contacts Calendars

Tags: ios, signature

**I am looking to create an app in order to deploy the signatures for a new enterprise.**

Can Xcode can access this part of the iPhone or is it is locked down by Apple?

Comment: I have seen previously that it was a locked API , just wondered if this might have changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the time of this writing (**iOS 9.2**).

Supporting evidence *(this answer has not been challenged since 2012)*:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463843/218152